# wp_update_user crashes my plugin for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to write a plugin which will update a user field. I can use the update user meta function OK, but when I try the wp_update_user it doesnt work.

```
wp_update_user($user_ID, 'user_nicename', 'test');
```

That crashes the plugin. 
Do I need to include something for this function to work??

Comment: What do you mean by "crash" exactly? What error messages do you get?

Comment: i don't get any errors, it just stops loading the plugin. So if I had <p>Hello</p><?php wp_update_user(...); ?><p>world</p> it wouldn't load the "world" part.

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: I have switched error reporting on and it says 'Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_update_user()'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the Codex on [`wp_update_user()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user) - you're not using it correctly. It should be;

```
wp_update_user(array('ID' => $user_ID, 'user_nicename' => 'test'));
```

Comment: yes sorry, I did actually have it set up like that, but I copied the wrong code for the example!

Comment: (I'd been trying so many different methods - I think that one was left over from the meta update call)

Comment: You're calling the function when it has not been loaded! `Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_update_user()` - where are you calling this function?

Comment: that makes sense.. I wasn't sure if I needed to include something or reference a class? I'm writing a plugin and want to allow the user to update the user_nicename from within the site (so not in the admin panel). thanks.

Comment: also, the plugin is called using a shortcode in a post. The shortcode [example] will draw the form which the user will edit their user_nicename. the shortcode also checks for $_POST vars, if present, it will then call the wp_update_user() method - which is where it fails.

Comment: In which case you will need to load in the registration functions yourself. Check to see if the function exists, it it does not, include `ABSPATH . WPINC . '/registration.php'`